# Ripples with border for a TextView?

Tags: android, ripple

I have few `TextView`s that are displayed  beside each other. Currently, I use `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` to get the ripple on touch.

Now, I would like to add borders to the `TextView`s when they are not pressed and have the ripple when the `TextView` is touched. How do I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on a [`Styling Android` blog post](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/ripples-part-2/):

> Another way that we can confine the bounds of a ripple animation is to
>   actually define a shape drawable as a child

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/card_set_bg_color"
                android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Here the `<solid>` in `<shape>` is needed for the ripple to render. If set to `transparent` or omitted, the ripple doesn't render. The ripple needs a solid background to render on. `TextView`s don't have a background color so we need to specify a `<solid>`.

Comment: Very genius solution, and +1 for answer from the questioner.